# connectionString.open() throws an error

Tags: c#, sql

I have successfully used the connection string generated by the Server explorer.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + "Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;"+"Integrated Security=True");
```

but as I write `myConnection.open();` it throws an error saying:

> Error  1   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'open' and no extension method 'open' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is a similar problem posted by someone over here in stackeverflow; here is the link

[Connecting to SQL Server in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947212/connecting-to-sql-server-in-asp-net)

From what I understand that question's OP says that along with the conenction string we also have to pass the sql command. But what I wish to do is to just open the connection and as some button is clicked then only the query is run. How do i just open the connection?

P.S. I have not missed a directive as I have written this command

> using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: It is anyway a bad idea to leave a connection open longer than the time you actually need it... But you should solve your problem by using a capital "O" as in `Open()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method names start with capital letters in C#. It should read

```
myConnection.Open();
```

By the way, the safest way to create a connection string is to use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class like this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = "SHIRWANIPC";
csb.InitialCatalog = "...";
...

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: You are my saviour :D

Comment: And i am an ass (please forgive me for this abuse ,i thought this was compulsury :P)

Comment: I don't feel abused :-D Glad I could help. Please see my edit and feel free to accept/upvote my answer.